# PyVirtualDisplay AttributeError: 'Display' object has no attribute 'old_display_var'

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyvirtualdisplay

I get

```
AttributeError: 'Display' object has no attribute 'old_display_var'
```

in PyVirtualDisplay when trying to stop display after tests execution:

in setUp method:

```
self.display = Display(visible=False, size=(1440, 900)) 
self.display.start()
```

then open browser and execute tests

and in tearDown method:

```
self.display.stop()
```

I want to stop display because of many opened Xvfb processes in ubuntu after several test execution

Comment: Were you able to determine a fix for this?  Just ran into this same issue and this appears to be the only SO question about it.  Not a huge deal, as I can just manually delete the Xvfb processes, but would be interested in a fix.

Comment: No, I did not resolve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same message yesterday. I forgot starting the display with 
`self.display.start()`

Adding this to the file resolved the issue.